# Creating a boxplot loop with ggplot2 for only certain variables

Tags: r, data-science

I have a dataset with 99 observations and I need to create boxplots for ones with a specific string in them. However, when I run this code I get 57 of the exact same plots from the original function instead of the loop. I was wondering how to prevent the plots from being overwritten but still create all 57. Here is the code and a picture of the plot.
Thanks!

[Boxplot Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/as6t5.png)

```
    #starting boxplot function
     myboxplot <- function(mydata=ivf_dataset, myexposure = 
     "ART_CURRENT", myoutcome = "MEG3_DMR_mean")
     {bp <- ggplot(ivf_dataset, aes(ART_CURRENT, MEG3_DMR_mean)) 
     bp <- bp + geom_boxplot(aes(group =ART_CURRENT))
     }

     #pulling out variables needed for plots
     outcomes = names(ivf_dataset)[grep("_DMR_", names(ivf_dataset), 
     ignore.case = T)]

     #creating loop for 57 boxplots
     allplots <- list()
     for (i in seq_along(outcomes))
     {
     allplots[[i]]<- myboxplot (myexposure = "ART_CURRENT", myoutcome = 
     outcomes[i])  
     }
     allplots
```

Comment: `bp <- ggplot(ivf_dataset, aes(ART_CURRENT, MEG3_DMR_mean))` is forcing the `MEG3_DMR_mean` to be in the plot. The arguments `myexposure` and `myoutcome` aren't used anywhere in your function.

Comment: I am new to R so pardon any ignorance I have. When I put myexposure and myoutcome into the function I no longer get any real boxplots and they all have the same x axis and still do not loop. Do you see any problem is the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend reading about standard and non-standard evaluation and how this works with the tidyverse. Here are some links

http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#function-arguments

http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html

I also found this useful

https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/97970_465837f898094848b293e3988a1328c6.html

Also, you need to produce an example so that it is possible to replicate your problem. Here is the data that I created.

```
df <- data.frame(label = rep(c("a","b","c"), 5), 
                x = rnorm(15),
                y = rnorm(15),
                x2 = rnorm(15, 10),
                y2 = rnorm(15, 5))
```

I kept most of your code the same and only changed what needed to be changed.

```
myboxplot2 <- function(mydata = df, myexposure, myoutcome){
 bp <- ggplot(mydata, aes_(as.name(myexposure), as.name(myoutcome))) +
   geom_boxplot()
 print(bp)
}
myboxplot2(myexposure =  "label", myoutcome =  "y")
```

Because `aes()` uses non-standard evaluation, you need to use `aes_()`. Again, read the links above.

Here I am getting all the columns that start with x. I am assuming that your code gets the columns that you want.

```
outcomes <- names(df)[grep("^x", names(df), ignore.case = TRUE)]
```

Here I am looping through in the same way that you did. I am only storing the plot object though.

```
allplots <- list()
for (i in seq_along(outcomes)){
  allplots[[i]]<- myboxplot2(myexposure = "label", myoutcome = outcomes[i])$plot
}
allplots
```